# Expected number of mistakes grows logarithmically in number of iterations - improving performance?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am reading a paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02162)) in which an algorithm proposes a solution $\hat{\mathbf x}^{(t)}$ in each iteration $t = 1, \dots, T$, and each time, learns the true solution $\mathbf x^{(t)}$, so we learn whether the algorithm made a mistake, i.e. $\hat{\mathbf x}^{(t)} \neq \mathbf x^{(t)}$.

In Theorem 9, we learn that the expected number of mistakes made by the algorithm after $T$ iterations is bounded by something like $O\left(\log(T)\right)$, ignoring terms I don't want to focus on here.

**Question:** Can we interpret this as implying that the algorithm is getting better over time? Asymptotically, $T$ will dominate $c \log(T)$ for some $c > 0$, so does this imply that over very many iterations, the algorithm should eventually rarely make mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it becomes clear if you see the error ratio:

$$r_T := \frac{T}{\log T} \ .$$

$r_T$ is a monotonic (strictly) decreasing sequence and $\lim\limits_{T\to 0} r_T = 0$, but $r_T>0 \ \forall \ T > 1$. This means that the error ratio becomes smaller and smaller as the number of iterations grow, until it becomes negligible.

However, be careful when working with asymptotics. $O(\log T)$ is just an asymptotical behavior, it can be that in practice, for a reasonable number of iterations, we don't have this improving behavior.